# Is fork Thread Safe?

Tags: c, fork

I checked the man page for the fork. It doesn't mention anything about the thread safety of this function.
Where can I check it or how to determine it?

Comment: Yes, no.  Please explain what you understand by 'thread-safe' in the context of fork.

Comment: Consider one thread locking the memory allocator within a call to `malloc` at the same time another's thread call to `fork` spawns the new process. The question is - how does the new process unlock the memory allocator (`malloc`) if no thread owns the lock?

Comment: If I look at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Process.html
It mentions ** MT-Safe**. Does that mean it is thread safe?